# Unwanted irregular interval between y-axis ticks, ggplot2 bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to create a simple bar chart in r using ggplot2 following http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_(ggplot2)/
When I run the code below the y-axis is not plotted on a continous scale. Instead the intervals are irregular with each tick set equal to a value I have inputted. How can I change the scale to have regular 10% intervals from 0% to -70%?

```
# Replicate dataset
seg=c(rep("City",2),rep("Supermini",2),rep("Small family",2),
rep("Large family",2),rep("MPV",2),
rep("Compact executive",2),rep("Executive",2),
rep("Sports",2),rep("SUV",2),rep("Luxury",2))

leg=rep(c("Cost","Mass"),10)

val=c(-0.26,-0.14, -0.34, -0.09, -0.21, -0.13, -0.09, -0.03, -0.22, -0.04,
-0.58, -0.24, -0.47,-0.44,-0.42,-0.14,-0.61,-0.39,-0.43,-0.03)

bardata=as.data.frame(cbind(seg,leg,val))

# Create bar chart
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(bardata, aes(factor(seg), val, fill = leg)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("deepskyblue4","deepskyblue2"))+
  labs(fill=NULL)+
  xlab(NULL)+
  ylab("Percentage change relative to base case")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `cbind` generates a matrix, which forces all columns to take on the same `class`. Instead, generate your data.frame with this:

```
bardata <- data.frame(seg,leg,val)
```

and it will preserve the separate classes of your data. When `ggplot` was plotting the `val` column as a factor, it had no way of knowing that it should actually be numeric.

Comment: That worked many thanks - wish I'd posted the question earlier!